# how to write shell script to run python in a loop?

Tags: python, shell

I have the python code as following:

```
t1=datetime.datetime.now()
t2=t1-datetime.timedelta(days=3)
sql="select * from tbl1 where thedate between %s and %s"%(t2,t1)
```

The python code is select data from t1 to t2, now I would like to write a shell script to set t1 from 2014.1.1 till today. and run the python code for each day. How could I do it?

Comment: Maybe by reading [an appropriate manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a shell script for this. You can just do it within python if you play with datetime.

```
t=datetime.datetime.today()
today=datetime.date(today.year, today.month, today.day) # needs to be a date object
t1=datetime.date(year=2014, month=1,day=1) # set initial date
while t1 < today : # from initial date to today
    t2=t1-datetime.timedelta(days=3*365)
    sql="select * from tbl1 where thedate between %s and %s"%(t2,t1)
    t1+=datetime.timedelta(days=1) # increment day
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The reason I need a script is that there other file I need to run the same time, or I will not ask for the script.

Comment: @wrwerwerwe if you elaborate a little more on what you want, then maybe i could be of more help!